# Swift generic class how to create a type object from it

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have a generic class, this should simply map a model into a view-model (and other stuff, but mostly this one).

```
class InfoProv <M, VM: CreationableFromModel> {
    var models = [M]()
    var viewModels = [VM]()
    func generateModelView() -> VM {
        return VM(model: M)
    }
}

protocol CreationableFromModel {
    typealias Model
    init(model: Model)
}
```

The conformity to the protocol `CreationableFromModel` tells that the view model must know how to create itself by using a Model type.
I really do not understand how to make "pass" to the VM init a valid instance of Model

Comment: I believe that you will need also a generic constraint `where VM.Model = M`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only minor problems in your code

```
protocol CreationableFromModel {
    typealias Model

    init(model: Model)
}

// you need a generic constraint to create a connection between the two generic types
class InfoProv <M, VM: CreationableFromModel where VM.Model == M> {
    var models = [M]()
    var viewModels = [VM]()

    func generateModelView(m: M) -> VM {
        // you were passing type M here, you need an instance m of type M
        return VM(model: m)
    }
}
```